# Solving $\tan (2x) = 6\cos^2(x) - 4\sin(x)\cos(x) - 2\sin^2(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

I need to solve the following trigonometric equation:

$$\tan (2x) = 6\cos ^2(x)  - 4\sin (x)\cos (x) - 2\sin ^2(x)$$

My attempt:

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)} = 3(\cos(2x)+1) - 2\sin(2x) -2(1-\cos^2(x))$$

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)} = 3\cos(2x)+3 - 2sin(2x) - 2(1-\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2})$$

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)} = 3\cos(2x)+3-2\sin(2x)-2+\cos(2x)+1$$

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)} = 4\cos(2x) +2 - 2\sin(2x)$$

Adding $2\sin(2x)$ to each side and then multiplying by $\cos(2x)$
$$\sin(2x)(1+2\cos(2x)) = 4\cos^2(2x)+2\cos(2x)$$

$$\sin(2x)(1+2\cos(2x)) +1= 4\cos^2(2x)+2\cos(2x)+1$$

$$\sin(2x)(1+2\cos(2x))+1 = (2\cos(2x)+1)^2$$

$$1 = (2\cos(2x)+1)) (2\cos(2x)+1 - \sin(2x))$$

After that I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find correctly that
$$
\tan2x=4\cos2x-2\sin2x+2
$$
Multiplying by $\cos2x$ leads to
$$
4\cos^22x-2\sin2x\cos2x+2\cos2x-\sin2x=0
$$
that can be rewritten as
$$
2\cos2x(2\cos2x-\sin2x)+(2\cos2x-\sin2x)=0
$$
so
$$
(2\cos2x+1)(2\cos2x-\sin2x)=0
$$
This splits into
$$
\cos2x=-\frac{1}{2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad \sin2x=2\cos2x
$$
and both are elementary.

Comment: Looking at the last equation before the split, you can also write it as $$\tan 2x-4\cos 2x+2\sin 2x-2=(1+2\cos(2x))(\tan(2x)-2)=0.$$ But good luck spotting that before the factorization. (Also, one of the roots in $[0,\pi]$ happens to be a double root. So that's neat.)